# SharePoint 2010 Central admin farm administrators group permissions removed cannot login

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I have removed the "**farm administrators**" group by using the "Remove Users Permissions" option whilst in the Central admins site, now when I try to login I get "Access Denied" does anybody know how to put the "farm administrators" back? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just to note that we had brought our SharePoint farm up to date with its patches just over a week ago, it contains (SharePoint 2010) `2 WFE Servers, 2 Application Servers and 2 SQL Servers`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you removed farm admin group and now every body getting access denined.
In order to access the Central admin.

- Please add yourself in the local Admin group on the server where Central admin is hosted.
- Log out from the server and re login.In order to take effect of that permision
- Now go to the Central Administration -> Security -> Manage farm administrators group.
- create / add user here.

Comment: Just tried that no joy. I get "Error Group cannot be found"

Comment: You able to login on central admin?

Comment: Nope, ever since I clicked remove on the farm admins I cannot login to CA, I had another account which had full control and even trying to login with that I get "Error Group cannot be found"

Comment: can you share the screen shot, i am little confused, i am trying to delete that group but from my VM but its says you cant.

Comment: Don't try and delete it just got to CA then go to Application Management then Manage service applications then user profile service application then site actions then site permissions, Then to remove “farm Administrators” This is what I did

Comment: sorry, what you mean by removed not delete?

Comment: Just to confirm I did not delete the group "farm admins" just removed the group from site permissions using the "remove user permissions"

Comment: can you browse this centraladmin url/_layouts/user.aspx with the account which having local admin on the server....try from server

Comment: No joy just get Error, access denied

Comment: under which account app pool of Central admin is running, try with that account...if no joy then i think is better to re provison the CEntral admin